# CLion: main.cpp does not recognize my function from tests.h

Tags: function, header-files, clion

I'm trying to do my homework. For each assignment we've been making functions in a functions.h file. Now my professor wants me to make test functions and include them in a separate tests.h file.

This is what my main looks like:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "tests.h"

int main() {
    pracProgDriver(ch5PracProg1());
    return 0;
}
```

But CLion gives me the following error:
No matching function for call to 'pracProgDriver'

Here is how I declared it in tests.h:

```
void pracProgDriver(void function());
```

However, it's not recognizing the pracProgDriver() function from tests.h and I don't know why. The function ch5PracProg1() from functions.h is recognized just fine. Why is this happening?

I tried removing
#include "functions.h"
from my main, as functions.h was included in tests.h. I wanted to see if this changed anything, and it changed nothing.

Comment: As a non-C++ expert, I see that you declare the parameter to be a function, but provide the result of that function instead. May this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is a function protoype, by themselves, prototypes are not definition of functions and can't be "imported".

In order to define a function you need to "add" brackets, but there's also a syntax error if what you want is to accept a void function.

If you want to keep the protoype your header will look like this:

```
void pracProgDriver(void (*fuction)()); // Prototype (it is not necessary and can be removed)

void pracProgDriver(void (*function)())
{
    function();
}
```

The original syntax indicates that there are no arguments to the function, which is not consistent with the intention of accepting an empty function as an argument.

**EDIT:** Also, your main file should look like this:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "tests.h"

int main() {
    pracProgDriver(ch5PracProg1);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that parentheses are gone.

Comment: Late reply, but this helped me. Thank you for answering!